# R - using ODBC it is slow getting dataframe into R

Tags: sql, r, performance, odbc

I am trying to figure out why my SQL query is taking so long to pull into R. I am working on a `shinydashboard` and trying to pull all my data from a SQL server but the elapsed time is just too slow for usability.

Using `odbc` package to pull from a Microsoft SQL Server.

I have attempted the query in two ways but both give very similar results.

```
> system.time(Shipments <- dbReadTable(con, "DataPrep_ShipmentsYear"))
   user  system elapsed 
 60.482   7.520 258.024 

> system.time(Shipments <- dbGetQuery(con, paste0("SELECT * FROM DataPrep_ShipmentsYear")))
   user  system elapsed 
 63.341   7.020 249.376

> system.time(Shipments <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM DataPrep_ShipmentsYear"))
   user  system elapsed 
 59.380   6.592 220.160

> system.time(Shipments <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT [X columns] FROM DataPrep_ShipmentsYear"))
   user  system elapsed 
 37.688   4.464 201.509
```

It is looking like it is the `user` time that is taking a long time, any guess what is causing that? I also, based on my own lack of knowledge, don't know why elapsed time != user + system. I would expect a dataset this size to take ~5 seconds.

About the dataset:

- 487,718 rows
- 116 columns
- classes:

  - numeric: 50
  - character: 56
  - Date: 9
  - Integer: 1

Unfortunately, I can't show the actual dataset due to it being company private but if anyone needs more information, please let me know and thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there more to your actual query? Wrapping `paste` around your query does nothing here. If you have other things you are trying to get in there (such as conditionals), then I argue *strongly* against `paste`, in lieu of using [parameterized queries](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/) (see https://xkcd.com/327).

Comment: Long "user" times can be due to many things: network bandwidth, DBMS performance, etc. Unfortunately, even with 476K rows, there's not a lot here for us to go on. As to your question about elapsed/user/system, have you read [`?proc.time`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/proc.time) (suggested by `?system.time`)?

Comment: Are you sure you always need all 116 columns and 487k rows for a *interactive Shiny* app?  If so and the database doesn't change frequently, you can hide that latency in [global.R](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html)

Comment: one thing that you can do (I usually do it) is use parallel package and create a function that would query the table. You can query chunks of data like 50,000 records in parallel. This would probably make it faster.

Comment: Hi everyone, @r2evans: I get what you are saying about `paste`. I have removed it but it does not change the time. @wibeasley: yes unfortunately I need all rows as people like to drill down into the details (each row is a shipment). However, I could probably get rid of some of the columns. That would help the performance. @Not_Dave: Are you able to put an example of how you do that?

Comment: I reduced the number of columns (still 74) and it got slightly better results but again, not a useable loading time.

Comment: Also @wibeasley, the dataset updates once a month (trying to get it down to once a week). I could hide it in global.R but I don't want to have to republish the app everytime it changes. Trying to make the app self-sufficient. Also it looks like hiding it in the global.R only works for a single R process so if I have multiple allowed processes, I'm not sure how well it will reduce the loading time.

Comment: @Kevin, my interpretation of the [Scoping rules for Shiny apps](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html) document is that variables declared in the global file "are visible in the server code across all sessions (multiple users could use a shared variable)".  I didn't realize they're available also to ui.R, which is probably a tad suboptimal, so put it in the server.R file, but outside the function.

Comment: @wibeasley, the issue I have is with this line _`create these objects once and share them across all user sessions (within the same R process)`_ . I am using RStudio Connect to have hundreds of users so there will be multiple R processes spun up to handle the load. So it will work for all the users in a process but once a new process needs to be created, one unlucky individual will have to wait the 4 minutes for everything to load for them.

Comment: @Kevin, there are strategies we use for caching, and this probably deserves it's own SO question.  In short, in this scenario we upload a Shiny-ready RDS to the Shiny server every ~10 minutes (in the global file).  This hides the database latency.

Comment: @wibeasley, I'm not familiar with RDS but I think we are doing something very similar. I have turned to running a scheduled R script that is creating an updated csv file every ~15 minutes but I am putting it in the server function (takes ~15 seconds to load). I am doing this because I have the data auto-refresh the dashboard every 90 minutes and I don't think I can achieve that putting it the global file.